# How to add both hardcode values and JSON values in jquery UI autcomplete?

Tags: json, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using jquery UI autocomplete plugin for state field.
here is my code :

autocomplete:

```
  {

  source: function( request, response ) {

            jQuery.ajax({
                url:base+"/stateSearchJSON",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                data: {
                    maxRows: 10,
                    startsWith: request.term

                },
                success: function( data ) {

                    response( jQuery.map( data.states, function( item ) {
                        return {
                                       value: item.stateName,
                                       label: item.stateName
                                  }

                    }));
                                        jQuery('.ui-autocomplete').css('width', '188px');
                }
            });
        }
  }
```

Now for state field I want add one hardcode value to autocomplete which is 'tristate'.
value with :
Label:'tristate',
value:CT,NY,NJ.

autocomplete should populate both JSON response and hardcode value which is tristate.

How can I incorporate both JSON and hardcode value for autocomplete?

Answer (score 0):

Via: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-search

Independent of the variant you use, the **label** is always treated as text.

If you want the label to be treated as html you can use Scott González' html extension:
 https://github.com/scottgonzalez/jquery-ui-extensions/blob/master/autocomplete/jquery.ui.autocomplete.html.js